# Converting this list of objects to json using LINQ

Tags: c#, json, linq, highcharts

I am trying to convert some data into a json object that HighCharts library is expecting for its series data. This is the format:

```
var series = [
        {
            name : "Duplicate Transactions"
            data : [190, 107]
        },
        {
            name : "Unique Transactions"
            data : [55, 51]
        }
    ]
```

I have list of objects like this in my backend code:

```
UsageData usageData = new UsageData()
{
    {UsageType = "FIND", DupTrans  = 190, UniqTrans = 55 },
    {UsageType = "PARTS", DupTrans  = 107, UniqTrans = 51 }
};
```

So far I have this:

```
var dup = usageData.GroupBy(d => d.DuplicateTransactions)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        name = "Duplicate Transactions",
        usageData = g.Select(c => c.DuplicateTransactions).ToArray()
    });

var uniq = usageData.GroupBy(d => d.UniqueTransactions)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        name = "Unique Transactions",
        usageData = g.Select(c => c.UniqueTransactions).ToArray()
    });
```

but the output I get is not as desired:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "Duplicate Transactions",
        "data" : [190]
    },
    {
        "name" : "Duplicate Transactions",
        "data" : [107]
    }
]

[
    {
        "name" : "Unique Transactions",
        "data" : [55]
    },
    {
        "name" : "Unique Transactions",
        "data" : [51]
    }
]
```

Comment: Could you point out what is wrong with the ouput? What's the expected format? It looks exactly as the first one. Edit: I think I get it tho it's still kind of confusing.

Comment: In the first one, data for each transaction is grouped. In the first object, data is 190 and 107 together. In my output, they are separated.

Comment: You are using `UniqueTransactions` and `DuplicateTransactions` properties as key for groups, so it grouped by them as they are unique. You don't need `GroupBy` here if you don't need to group items by key. You need to remove `GroupBy` call and use just `Select` call without grouping.

Comment: Okay, so I removed the GroupBy and just did this:             `var uniq = data.Select(d => new
                {
                    name = "Unique Transactions",
                    data = d.UniqueTransactions
                });`

Still gives me the same output.

Comment: Why didn't I go the obvious route? Always overthinking stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one more data class which will be serialized. Refer below code.

```
 class Output
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int[] DupTrans { get; set; }
}

class UsageData
{
    public string UsageType { get; set; }
    public int DupTrans { get; set; }
    public int UniqTrans { get; set; }
}
 List<UsageData> usageData = new List<UsageData>()
        {
            new UsageData(){UsageType = "FIND", DupTrans  = 190, UniqTrans = 55 },
            new UsageData(){UsageType = "PARTS", DupTrans  = 107, UniqTrans = 51 }
        };

        var myObj = new { Name = "Duplicate Transactions", DupTrans = usageData.Select(x => x.DupTrans).ToArray() };
        string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your approach, but with anonymous types.

Comment: updated my post with anonymous types. Sorry I was thing only about output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my variant:

```
var usageData = new List<UsageData>()
{
    new UsageData {UsageType = "FIND", DupTrans  = 190, UniqTrans = 55 },
    new UsageData {UsageType = "PARTS", DupTrans  = 107, UniqTrans = 51 }
};

var dup = usageData
        .GroupBy(p => "Duplicate Transactions", p => p.DupTrans)
        .Select(g => new {
            name = "Duplicate Transactions",
            data = g.ToList()
        }).First();

Console.WriteLine(dup.name);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", dup.data));

var uniq  = usageData
            .GroupBy(p => "Unique Transactions", p => p.UniqTrans)
            .Select(g => new {
                name = "Unique Transactions",
                data = g.ToList()
            }).First();

Console.WriteLine(uniq.name);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", uniq.data));
```

This sample is using constant key as group key, so all items will be grouped into one, and then it can be used with serializer.

Following code produces such output with `Console.WriteLine`:

```
Duplicate Transactions
190,107
Unique Transactions
55,51
```

Here is a working sample in DotNetFiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/IEwoDC

Answer (score 0):

What you might have wanted is this:

```
var grp = usageData
                .GroupBy(u => u.name)
                .Select(g => new 
                    { 
                        name = g.Key, 
                        data = g.Select(u => u.data).ToArray() 
                    });
```

I based this on the data you initially supplied (as in output of above query matches the one below):

```
var series = [
    {
        name : "Duplicate Transactions"
        data : [190, 107]
    },
    {
        name : "Unique Transactions"
        data : [55, 51]
    }
]
```

This would assume that your class is something like this:

```
class serie
{
    public string name;
    public int data;
}
```

And that your data is something like this:

```
var usageData = new[] 
{
    new serie { name = "Duplicate Transactions", data = 190 },
    new serie { name = "Duplicate Transactions", data = 107 },
    new serie { name = "Unique Transactions", data = 55 },
    new serie { name = "Unique Transactions", data = 51 },
}
```

The way you designed your class isn't consistent with anything above:

```
UsageData usageData = new UsageData()
{
    {UsageType = "FIND", DupTrans  = 190, UniqTrans = 55 },
    {UsageType = "PARTS", DupTrans  = 107, UniqTrans = 51 }
};
```

So I'm not sure I helped but the example I provided will definitely produce the JSON results you initially posted.

I haven't tested this in VS with your data so tell me if you have troubles testing this or understanding.